# Split edges in the road network of OpenStreetMap

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, postgis

I have a road network stored in OpenStreetMap format. Most of the edges are too long. I want to add nodes to the edge to make sure the length of each edge is less than 5 meters. Is there a automatic way to do this? I tried to manually add edges through JOSM, but there are too much work.

Comment: Try GRASS: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.split.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try transforming the OSM file into PBF using [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Examples) and then loading the PBF file into an [Atlas](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas#building-an-atlas-from-an-osmpbf-file). That will give you a lot of [easy-to-use APIs](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas#using-atlas) around the roads. What you want to do is not pre-implemented there, but you could easily get to it from there.